# Error loading image form from shape sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to load an image in a form that comes from a shape in a sheets. but then the error message appears.

```
Sub gbrload()
Me.Image1.Picture = Sheets("GBR").Shapes("Picture 21").Fill
End Sub
```

Can anyone fix that?

Comment: Not possible (in my understanding). Either make another userform with all the pictures so you can call them from that userform, use frames, load them directly from directory or create code that will make a picture from the image (makes sense?) and loads that into userform.

Comment: I used to use shift between images only in sheets only. and now I want to display it in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

```
Sub gbrload()
Me.Image1.Picture = Sheets("GBR").Shapes("Picture 21").picture
End Su
```